# Vue Transition on Element When Route Changes

Tags: vue.js

## Context:

I have a navigation component which is present on every page but there is a logo element in that component which I am removing based on what route the user is at. I want to add a transition effect to this element when it disappears/appears and I have tried to do so using Vue transitions as you can see down below.

### Problem is:

Element only fades in when `this.header` goes from false to true - whenever it goes from true to false no animation happens.

You can look at the problem for yourself in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mzpw4rkn9y)

### Sidenote:

The CSS is not the problem. I know this because the desired effect works perfectly well if I instead trigger it using a button. The problem seems to have something to do with the nature of using a router change to trigger the animation. Do any of you have any idea why this would be the case?

```
<template>
  <div class="headerNav">

      <transition name="fade">
        <div class="logo" v-if="!this.logo"></div>
      </transition>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Navbar',
    components: {
      postFilter,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        logo: null,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      //changing around the header depending on the page we are on so that we can use one header for all pages
      if (this.$route.name == 'Library' || this.$route.name == 'Profile') {
        this.logo = false
      } else {
        this.logo = true
      }
  }
</script>
```

The CSS (this should not be a problem but I included it anyway)

```
.fade-enter-active {   
    transition: all .3s ease; 
} 
.fade-leave-active {   
    transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0); 
} 
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {   
    transform: translateY(10px);   opacity: 0; 
}
```

Comment: I know it works without the router. That's the problem. As I said in the post, it specifically stops working correctly when the trigger for the change is the router. That's the problem I am trying to solve, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked that this.logo is indeed set to false when the page is switched and it appears to be in order. In fact the problem is just that the transition does no occur, despite this the logo still goes away when the page changes so that seems to be in order. It's just the transition animation that is not working correctly.

Comment: I used code sandbox to recreate the problem. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/mzpw4rkn9y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and codesandboxes, here is a working version:  https://codesandbox.io/s/olz3jrk829

Two main changes:

Instead of

```
<transition name="fade">
  <div class="logo" v-if="page"></div>
</transition>
<transition name="fade">
  <div class="logo two" v-if="!page"></div>
</transition>
```

Combine both `div` in one transition. [Vue needs keys to determine each section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements):

```
<transition name="fade">
  <div v-if="page" class="logo" key="1">12</div>
  <div v-else class="logo two" key="2">34</div>
</transition>
```

Use the `computed` function instead of `mounted`:

```
computed: {
    page() {
      if (this.$route.name == 'otherpage') {
        return false
      } else {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
```

Most importantly, you reuse your `navigation` in each component (`home`and `otherpage` in your example), so the leave transition doesn't get triggered from mounting.

The right way would be to remove the `navigation` component from the `home` and `otherpage` component, so it gets used only **once** in `App.vue`, which let all other components share **one** `navigation` instance.

Here is your original question with the changes:

```
<template>
  <div class="headerNav">

      <transition name="fade">
        <div v-if="logo" class="logo" key="1"></div>
        <div v-else class="logo two" key="2"></div>
      </transition>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Navbar',
    components: {
      postFilter,
    },
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    computed: {
      logo() {
        if (this.$route.name == 'Library' || this.$route.name == 'Profile') {
          return false
        } else {
          return true
        }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would upvote your comment but I dont have the reputation for it,

Comment: I think there should not be any parentheses after `computed:`